# Custom Font color (Dark Navy Blue)

Tags: uicolor, uifont, custom-font

I'm trying to make a font the same color as a detail disclosure button (dark purple or dark navy blue).

I used the following combination `[UIColor colorWithRed: 187.0/255.0f green:107.0/255.0f blue:207.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]` but it is not even close. Can anyone please provide me with the right combination of red green and blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For color of the **background** of a detail disclosure button you'll want something like:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: 28./255.f green:86./255.f blue:207./255.f alpha:1.0]
```

For the **font color** of a standard UIButton:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: 38./255.f green:60./255.f blue:113./255.f alpha:1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `[UIColor colorWithRed: 0f green:0f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0]` should be closer.

If you want other colors, use a color chart [like this one on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names), and just convert the percentages to values between 0 and 1 (e.g. 30% = 0.3)

Comment: I don't know about this. Thanks for this.